# What is the equivalent of WebViewPage.InitializePage() in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

In ASP.NET MVC (not Core) we were able to create a class that derives from `WebViewPage` and set it as the base class for all razor views (by setting the value of the `pageBaseType` attribute in the pages element in web.config).

In that custom base class, we were able to override the `InitializePage()` method and access the context object of the current request in that overridden method.

Now that has changed in ASP.NET Core. We now have to derive a class from the `RazorPage` class (and set it as the base class for all razor views in `_ViewImports.cshtml`). More importantly, the `InitializePage()` method no longer exists in the new `RazorPage` class.

What I'm trying to do is find an equivalent to the removed `InitializePage()` method which I can override and access the context object from it. More specifically, I need to get some values from the `Context.Items` collection of the current request.

PLEASE NOTE:
I was able to do what I want by adding a property to the custom razor page base class and accessing the the context object in the getter of that property. But, I'd rather do it the old way, i.e. by overriding some method in the custom razor page base class and accessing the context object of the current request in that method. I'm trying to set the values of all properties at once instead of accessing the context object every time a property value is accessed.

Comment: Rather than trying to duplicate the old behavior in an entirely new framework, look for the idiomatic way of doing whatever you want to do in the new framework. Page-cycle events no longer exist in ASP.NET Core since it's stateless. To make it clear: there is no equivalent

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto I get it, thanks